# Error in goto module [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ok, let me start by saying I know that it is bad that I am using the goto module and I shouldn't be and blah blah blah. However, for this specific purpose I need it. Let me also say that I am new to Python so try to avoid complicated answers, thanks!

So with that out of the way let me now explain my issue (*I am on Linux*). When I run my little program, it runs fine until I hit my first string input. After I type in the string and press enter, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
      empid = input("Example Input: ")
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/goto.py", line 255, in _trace
     _addToCaches(filename)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/goto.py", line 230, in _addToCaches
      in tokenize.generate_tokens(open(moduleFilename, 'r').readline):
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<string>'
```

I have tried reinstalling the module, reinstalling python, and I'm not too sure that *string* would really be incorporated into goto.py anyway.

Thanks,
**Cether**

EDIT:
As requested, here is the code that leads up to the problem:

```
from goto import *
import time
import sys
import os

label .start
os.system('clear')
print "Example Printout"



exampin = input("Example Input: ")
```

The error happens when I press enter after I enter the string in that input.

Comment: Please show the code that leads up to the error.

Comment: "I'm new to python, therefore I'm using goto" makes about as much sense as "I'm new to python, therefore I'm using eval". I'd recommend getting to know the language before you start pulling stuff like that :P

Comment: @NightShadeQueen goto is a module that requires little to no previous knowledge of python. If you are unfamiliar with the module it can be located here: [link](http://entrian.com/goto/)

Comment: @Cether If you need goto, you're using Python wrong. In the link you specify, it even says it's an April Fools Day joke, meant to *never ever* be used in real code. It doesn't even guarantee that it will work in future versions of Python (which may be the reason why this isn't working).

Comment: "A Real Programmer can write FORTRAN programs in any language," is that it?

Comment: @wallyk I edited the post to show the code that leads to the problem.

Comment: Also, you're using Python 2 and the plain `inpu()` rather than `raw_input()`, which is probably the real cause of the problem. What are you entering at the prompt?

Comment: There are many, many things wrong with this. *Why* do you need `goto`? Why is `input` being used instead of `raw_input`? Are you sure you really need to run `os.system('clear')`?

Comment: @Kupiaskos I am aware that it was an April Fools Day joke. However, I wanted to test it. And I was only asking so I could fix the problem. I am interested as to what is causing the error.

Comment: @Cether As far as I can tell, the problem is that the `goto` module injects itself into every line of Python executed. `input()` executes arbitrary code in-memory, without a filename. `goto` expects every line executed to map to an existing filename. It's an April Fool's Day joke; it doesn't have to be rigorous.

Comment: @Cether, your question says that you need the `goto` module for your program, but then you comment above that you know it's a joke and you're just interested in why it doesn't work? Which one is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`goto.py` is an [April Fool's Day joke](http://entrian.com/goto/index.html). Do not ever use it. If you are using it seriously, you are not using Python seriously. However, the source is quite simple, so one can find out why this happens, from a purely academic viewpoint.

`goto.py:284` contains the line `sys.settrace(_trace)`. The [sys.settrace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) function is designed to be used by debuggers, and basically "catches" each line of Python before it actually executes, to create these pseudo-syntaxes. The function `_trace` defined on line 251 assumes that each line of code that is about to be executed has an associated filename, and that filename can be opened.

However, when the `input` function is run, it executes arbitrary Python code to evaluate, the string. This is a terrible default, but that's what it does, and it was changed in Python 3 to only return a string. When the code is being evaluated, it considers its filename to be `<string>`. This filename does not exist, so when the `_trace` function sees the code, it can't open the filename and crashes while "debugging".

The solution: ensure that you are never executing code that doesn't have an existing file associated with it. Avoid `eval`, `input`, `exec`, and anything that evaluates code outside of a file. Use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: That was my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Cether As usual, the word of warning: don't use `goto`. Nearly every situation in which `goto` would make sense in C can be replaced with loops, functions, and exceptions. Out of curiosity, why do you honestly need `goto` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

There is no use case where you would absolutely need goto in Python. In the worst case, use a [continuation](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/~duchier/python/continuations.html) and keep track of your state more manually.